# Replace value from a column based on condition of another column, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Starting DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A' : ['red','green','yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'blue'],
                   'Column B' : [NaN, 'blue', 'purple', NaN, NaN, NaN],
                   'Column C' : [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7]})
```

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'red' | NaN | 1 |
| 'green' | 'blue' | 2 |
| 'yellow' | 'purple' | 3 |
| 'orange' | NaN | 2 |
| 'red' | NaN | 3 |
| 'blue' | NaN | 7 |

Desired Result

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'red' | NaN | 1 |
| 'blue' | 'blue' | 2 |
| 'purple' | 'purple' | 3 |
| 'orange' | NaN | 2 |
| 'red' | NaN | 3 |
| 'blue' | NaN | 7 |

I want to replace values in column A only if the value in Column B is not NaN, and to replace column A with the value in Column B

So that I can run the following code:

`df[[Column_A, Column_C]].groupby(Column_A).sum()`

Which would result in the following DataFrame:

| Column A | Column C |
| --- | --- |
| 'red' | 4 |
| 'blue' | 9 |
| 'purple' | 3 |
| 'orange' | 2 |

I am trying to replace categories before doing a `groupby` call.

**Attempts:**

The DataFrame I am working with has a sequential numerical based index going from 0 to N. 
So I could hard code the following: 
`df.iloc[[index], column] = some_string` 
I do not want to do this as it is not dynamic and the DataFrame data could change.

I believe I could use `.agg()` or `.apply()` on either the `df` or the `df.groupby()` but this is where I have struggled.

Particularly with how to write a function to use with `.agg()` or `.apply()`

Say:

```
def my_func(x):
    print(x)
```

Then: 
`df.apply(my_func)` 
The result is the first column of `df` printed. 
Or: 
`df.apply(my_func, axis = 1)`

The result is the following format for each row:

```
Column A    red
Column B    Nan
Column C    1
Name: 0, dtype: object
Column A    green
Column B    blue
Column C    2
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

I am not sure how to access each column per row in `my_func`.

Edit: 
I am trying to find a way to change the value in Column A if the value, for that row, in Column B is not NaN. The value to use for replacing is the value in Column B, the value to replace is the value in Column A if Column B is not NaN.

But I want to do this dynamically, meaning not hardcoded as I showed with: 
`df.iloc[[index], column] = some_string`

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want only the first step? `df.loc[df['Column B'].notna(), 'Column A'] = df['Column B']`

Comment: @mozway I did an edit, apologies for not being clear. And thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*dynamic*", maybe `df.assign(**{'Column A': lambda d: d['Column A'].mask(d['Column B'].notna(), d['Column B'])})` or `df.assign(**{'Column A': lambda d: d['Column B'].fillna(d['Column A'])})`

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you could use `pd.apply` like this:

```
df['Column A'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Column B'] if str(x['Column B']) not in ['nan', 'NaN'] else x['Column A'], axis=1)

  Column A Column B  Column C
0      red      NaN         1
1     blue     blue         2
2   purple   purple         3
3   orange      NaN         2
4      red      NaN         3
5     blue      NaN         7
```

Notice that apply is not fast at for very large dataset is not advisable. There are some good [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) out there for alternative methods